# Get the Debug.Assert condition as a string on fail

Tags: c#

I'm building up tooling for a piece of software and would like to be able save out the boolean expression in the source code that exists in a `Debug.Assert` (or `Trace.Assert`) call.

For example, if the program crashes with:

```
var x = -1;
Debug.Assert(x >= 0, "X must be non-negative", "some detail message");
```

I'd like to be able to get out the string `"x >= 0"` as well as the message and detail message.

I've looked into using a [`TraceListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but `TraceListener#Fail(string)` and `TraceListener#Fail(string, string)` only can capture the message and detail message fields (which, in the case a developer does not include, leaves me with no easy way to report what went wrong).

I suppose it's possible to create a stack trace and read the particular line that failed and report that (assuming the source code is available), but this seems relatively fragile.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Perhaps create an expression, pass in the expression to the assert, then if it fails construct your string from the expression.

Comment: If one of the answers sufficiently addressed your question, you may want to select it as the answer, so that this question can be removed from the "unanswered" list.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. While all answers involving passing an expression technically would work, I unfortunately cannot go through and change the many existing `Debug.Assert` statements and enforce a new developer practice... perhaps I can do some code transformation, but that would incur [probably] unnecessary costs of evaluating the assert condition expressions (maybe in a special "really really debug" build?)

Comment: @MichaelTang, due to the `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute, the code for any `DebugEx.Assert` call would only be present in a debug build. But you are right evaluating the expressions, by compiling them will make things much slower. You could provide an additional variant, like `[Conditional("VERIFY")]` where you have a special build that defines this symbol, and a "DEBUG" variant that takes a `Func<bool>` as its `assertion` argument. That way there is no need to change the client code for the different builds.

Comment: I think I want all of our debug asserts for all of our debug builds; I'm not sure if the cost of compiling expressions is something I want to incur (as well as the cost of getting devs to start writing expression lambdas instead of just writing out the condition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use expressions to accomplish something rough:

```
public static class DebugEx
{
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void Assert(Expression<Func<bool>> assertion, string message)
    {
        Debug.Assert(assertion.Compile()(), message, assertion.Body.ToString());
    }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
var i = -1;
DebugEx.Assert(() => i > 0, "Message");
```

There are some down sides to this. The first is, you have to use a lambda, so that complicates the syntax a little bit. The second is since we are dynamically compiling things, there is a performance hit. Since this will only happen in Debug mode (hence the conditional), the performance loss won't be seen in Release mode.

Lastly, the output isn't pretty. It'll look something like this:

> (value(WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass0).i > 0)

There isn't a whole lot you can do about this. The reason this happens is because of the closure around `i`. This is actually accurate since that is what it gets compiled down into.

Answer (score 4):

I had already started typing an answer when @vcsjones posted his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777930/2573395), so I abandoned mine, but I see there are some parts of it that are still relevant. Primarily with regards to formatting the lambda expression into something readable, So I will merge his with that part of my intended answer.

It uses a number of regular expressions to format the assertion expression, so that in many cases it will look decent (i.e. close to what you typed).

For the example given in @vcsjones answer it will now look like this:

> Assertion '(i > 0)' failed.

```
public static class DebugEx
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Regex, string> _replacements;

    static DebugEx()
    {
        _replacements = new Dictionary<Regex,string>()
        {
            {new Regex("value\\([^)]*\\)\\."), string.Empty},
            {new Regex("\\(\\)\\."), string.Empty},
            {new Regex("\\(\\)\\ =>"), string.Empty},
            {new Regex("Not"), "!"}
        };
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void Assert(Expression<Func<bool>> assertion, string message)
    {
        if (!assertion.Compile()())
            Debug.Assert(false, message, FormatFailure(assertion));
    }

    private static string FormatFailure(Expression assertion)
    {
        return string.Format("Assertion '{0}' failed.", Normalize(assertion.ToString()));
    }

    private static string Normalize(string expression)
    {
        string result = expression;
        foreach (var pattern in _replacements)
        {
            result = pattern.Key.Replace(result, pattern.Value);
        }
        return result.Trim();
    }
}
```